# Why is SQL rowcount not returning in my stored procedure output parameter?

Tags: sql-server, rowcount, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure with pseudocode like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myProcedure(@param1 int, @param2 int, @returnCode int output)
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT .... -- my query here

   SET @returnCode = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

However, when I execute this stored procedure, @returnCode is NULL:

```
DECLARE @returnCode INT
EXEC myProcedure 1, 1, @returnCode
SELECT @returnCode
```

Returns NULL.

However, if I just do a select within the proc rather than setting the return code - `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` - I get the correct row count.

How can I return this row count in the output param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `OUTPUT` Keyword when executing the Procedure:

```
DECLARE @returnCode INT
EXEC myProcedure 1, 1, @returnCode OUTPUT
SELECT @returnCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed output parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(@param1 int, @param2 int, @returnCode int output)
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT 1
   UNION 
   SELECT 2;
   SET @returnCode = @@ROWCOUNT
END

DECLARE @returnCode INT
EXEC myProcedure 1, 1, @returnCode OUTPUT
SELECT @returnCode
```